# waitress insists on using port 5000

Tags: python, waitress

example code is [here](https://medium.com/brillio-data-science/exposing-your-data-science-project-to-the-world-flask-with-a-waitress-8592f0356b27)

In particular

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run() ##Replaced with below code to run it using waitress
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

produces the result

- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

and I can access it on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ only. I can change the port number to anything but waitress insists on using port 5000.

This must be something simple and obvious. What am I doing wrong? I am running windows 10.

PS. Waitress version 1.4.4

PPS. Flask does the same thing if I do app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 80) it still runs on 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Mybad! I was running it from Pycharm IDE by right clicking the script tab and selecting Run (ctrl-shift-F10). When I run it from the command line eg. python test.py it works fine.