# Cannot modify port, windows port setting problem

Tags: python, flask, web

Why I cannot modify FLASK port

```
#cmd
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

I used serve or app.run() and set port=5566, always not work

```
#index.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5566)
    #app.run()
```

I set windows11 fire wall input/output rule, all allow, port:5566 ,but system show me didn't open the port:5566

And at server pc type "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" I can upload image by FLASK,server pc can get the image, but will appear "Internal Server Error" lead to I cannot return anything.

Other user type "IP" can connect to website but cannot upload image, type "IP:5000" or "IP:5566", cannot link to website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try running it from the command line.**
(I mean the windows one not one built in to an editor)
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060292/waitress-insists-on-using-port-5000?rq=2), it helped.
To do this, open a command prompt by pressing WINDOWS + R then type`cmd`.
Then type `python <yourscript>.py`
Also try [running the command promt as an admin](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-open-a-windows-11-command-prompt-as-administrator/).

Comment: I used cmd to excute python instead of flask run,it work ! thank you